# Footer always visible in Bootstrap modale/accordion

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

### [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egNryZ)

Hello,

I'm desperately looking for a simple solution to my problem, my code is available on codepen.

```
// line 84
.panel-group .panel-heading + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
   border: none;
   max-height: 300px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The objective is to keep the pink footer always visible (pasted at the bottom of the screen), even if the content is too large (like the panel 3 when it is open).

I tried putting a vertical scroll when the content is too large, but I'm not sure how to use max-height in the best way (currently at 300px, line 84).

This solution does not really work, it is not suitable for those with large screens (because max-height: 300px ...).

Would it be possible to do what I want directly in CSS? If so, can you guide me?

Or Javascript is mandatory according to you? The background-gray of the panel must cover the whole area, down to the bottom, with any resolution.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
    .modal-body 
{
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height:400px;
}
```

Your modal body can be made scroll-able to keep footer always visible.You can use any height you want.

Comment: This is not a solution, the content does not fit the height of the screen.
The goal is not to have white between the panel 3 (when it is open) and the pink frame. The bottom must be gray.

Comment: Well, If you are planning to make a shopping cart in a modal, you don't need to apply Fixed position to footer. 

refer to this: http://phpexpertfoodordering.in/webslogix/html/menu.html

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should break the footer out of the modal and display it separately because the modal is already a fixed element. You could hook into `js` modal events and display this standalone footer only when modal is opened.

```
.modal-footer.outer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
    background: #fff;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpbYeE

Your modal footer was being `fixed`, it actually was behaving properly, the problem is that it's still a child of another fixed item - the modal itself and thus gets detached when the viewport gets too small for the parent.

http://g.recordit.co/pyMEfO94wE.gif

Comment: Your solution does not answer my request ...
The Footer must be precisely in the modal, it is the specifications ...

Thank you though.